# Use of belongs_to vs embedded_in in Rails Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

```
Rails 6
MongoDB
Mongoid
```

I am following the MongoDB web site, brief, and not documented tutorial sample.

There are a couple of models:

```
Post
Comment
```

I created Post, as follows:

```
rails g scaffold Post title:string body:text
```

And then created Comment, as follows:

```
rails g scaffold Comment name:string message:string post:belongs_to
```

Here's the auto-generated code:

models/post.rb:

```
class Post
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  field :title, type: String
  field :body, type: String

  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
end
```

models/comment.rb:

```
class Comment
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :name, type: String
  field :message, type: String

  embedded_in :post
end
```

In comment.rb, I was expecting:

```
belongs_to :post
```

Is embedded_in the right thing to use, or should I change it to: belongs_to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The tutorial](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/master/tutorials/getting-started-rails/#add-comments) instructs changing `embedded_in` to `belongs_to`.